# postgresql jsonb contains key:value on second level

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Is there a possibility in postgresql to query for a key:value on the second level

for example the jsonb field of a row looks like this:

```
{
   "something": {
      "v_id": "5544d28431f19", 
      "value": "xyz"
   }, 
   "something_else": {
      "v_id": "5544d28431feb", 
      "value": "abc"
   }
}
```

I want to query for this row using the v_id value like:

```
  SELECT id, jsonb_field
  FROM table_1
  WHERE jsonb_field @> '{{"v_id": "5544d28431feb"}}'
  ;
```

However, this query is not valid. How to achieve such a query?

**Edit:**

According to @CraigRinger's comment:

The point here is that I don't know the top level key, I want to say "for any object, is there an inner object that has the following key with the following value".

Comment: So the point here is that you don't know the top level key, you want to say "for any object, is there an inner object that has the following key with the following value" ?

Comment: @CraigRinger That is exactly the point

Comment: Thanks, wanted to clarify. I don't think this'll be able to use a jsonb index; it's probably going to be seqscan-only material unless you create an expression index just for this query.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for your comment. I haven't really considered specifying `v_id` as a jsonb index. Would you recommend me doing so and why would this not be possible here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `lateral join` to call `jsonb_each` for each row in your table.  The function `jsonb_each` turns each node into a row with two columns called `key` and `value`:

```
select  value
from    table_1
cross join lateral
        jsonb_each(jsonb_field) sub
where   value @> '{"v_id": "5544d28431feb"}';
```

Full example (no SQL Fiddle support for Postgres 9.4 yet):

```
create table table_1 (id int primary key, jsonb_field jsonb);
insert into table_1 (id, jsonb_field) values (42, '{
   "something": {
      "v_id": "5544d28431f19", 
      "value": "xyz"          
   },                                       
   "something_else": {
      "v_id": "5544d28431feb", 
      "value": "abc"
   }
}');

select  value
from    table_1
cross join lateral
        jsonb_each(jsonb_field) t2
where   value @> '{"v_id": "5544d28431feb"}';
```

This prints:

```
                   value                   
-------------------------------------------
 {"v_id": "5544d28431feb", "value": "abc"}
```

Comment: Hi Andomar, your example works perfect. Thanks a lot. However, I have a minor question: why do you use a `lateral_join`? I was able to get the same results with: `FROM table_1 t1, jsonb_each(json_field) t2`. I could not see a different performance with my small test-data. Is there any difference here?

Comment: It looks like `lateral` is implied if you use a function in a join, see the [9.3 release notes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3). So it's okay to omit `lateral` here.